# How to access shared volume in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

I am building a docker image from Cloud Build and trying to access shared volume inside Dockerfile, but it's not able to find the volume.

RUN pip install root/build_cache/package_folder

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  id: clone_repo
  args: ['source', 'repos', 'clone', 'github_repository_name', '/build_cache']
  volumes:
  - name: 'build_cache'
    path: '/root/build_cache'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--network=cloudbuild', '-t', 'gcr.io/project/cloud_run-pubsub_example', './cloud-run/file_upserter/']
  waitFor: ['clone_repo']
  volumes:
  - name: 'build_cache'
    path: '/root/build_cache'


Error message:

Step #1: Step 3/7 : RUN pip install build_cache/package_folder
Step #1: ---> Running in fe3e0ee08746
Step #1: ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'build_cache/package_folder'
Step #1: Hint: It looks like a path. File 'build_cache/package_folder' does not exist.
```

Comment: Anything that runs in a Dockerfile never has access to volumes.  They’re only attached to running containers after the `docker build` step is complete.

Comment: Also for each of the build steps that you are specifying, Cloud Build creates a different container, as per the documentation: "For each build step, Cloud Build executes a docker container as an instance of docker run."

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to do is incorporate build caching into a container build. The mechanisms for doing that in containers should use layer caching. Cloud Build's solution for that is Kaniko: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/kaniko-cache.

Comment: Will try kaniko-cache